# How do I add a relation parameter to my filter query?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, array

I am building an AJAX post filter using a single form with three select fields that allow the user to sort by three separate taxonomies (`category`, `region`, and `country`). Everything is working well for each select field when used alone, but when I choose options in two or three of the fields I want to make sure that the `tax_query` array has an additional `relation` parameter set to `AND` so that post results meet all of the conditions set in each field. Here's where I am starting from:

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order'     => $_POST['date'],
);

// Regions
if ( isset( $_POST['region_filter'] ) ) {
  $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'region',
      'field'    => 'id',
      'terms'    => $_POST['region_filter']
    )
  );
}

// Countries
if ( isset( $_POST['country_filter'] ) ) {
  $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'country',
      'field'    => 'id',
      'terms'    => $_POST['country_filter']
    )
  );
}

// Categories
if ( isset( $_POST['category_filter'] ) ) {
  $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
      'field'    => 'id',
      'terms'    => $_POST['category_filter']
    )
  );
}

if (
  isset( $_POST['region_filter'] ) && isset( $_POST['country_filter'] ) ||
  isset( $_POST['region_filter'] ) && isset( $_POST['category_filter'] ) ||
  isset( $_POST['country_filter'] ) && isset( $_POST['category_filter'] ) ||
  isset( $_POST['region_filter'] ) && isset( $_POST['country_filter'] ) && isset( $_POST['category_filter'] )
) {
  // All conditions must be true to return posts
  $args['tax_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' );
}

$filter_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Where am I missing the mark here? And a side question, the method I'm using to build my query seems very repetitive, and I'm sure there has to be a better, more DRY method I can use to trim this down a good bit. Suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your code blocks will overwrite the previous, you need to add to the array rather than replace it:

```
$args['tax_query'][] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'region',
    'field'    => 'id',
    'terms'    => $_POST['region_filter']
);
```

`relation` is `AND` by default, so you can just omit it, but if you wanted to explicitly set it:

```
$args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
```